# Prove: at most two circles are needed to be tangent to all the circle sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, euclidean-geometry, mobius-inversion

Construct a circle sequence $\{C_n\}$ (e.g., blue in the figure below) in 2D Cartesian coordiante system as:

1. the $x$-coordiantes of centers of all the circle $C_n$ are $\frac{1}n$;
2. all the circles $\{C_n\}$ are above and tangent to $x$ axis;
3. all the circles $C_n$ are tangent to their neighbour circles, i.e., $C_{k}$ is tangent to both $C_{k-1}$ and $C_{k+1}$, $\forall k>1$

Prove: there needs at most two circles (e.g., the red cirlces in the figure below) to be tangent to all the circles $\{C_n\}$.

**update:**

I mean there exists a set of circles such that no circle in the defined sequence is not tangent to a member of the circle set. Now prove the least upper bound of the set number is 2

I was considering to use inversion to transform the two red circles into two horizontal lines, but failed to obtain an explicit form

[image]
[image]

[A comment](https://mathoverflow.net/q/424139/483608) from mathoverflow which I have difficulty in understanding:

> This requires almost nothing about the set of circles Cn except its infinitude. The only other fact we need is that they're not all tangent to each other at the same point. Indeed for any three circles Σ1,Σ2,Σ3 there are finitely many circles C tangent to each Σi (i=1,2,3), unless the Σi are tangent to each other at the same point P and then every other C must also be tangent to them at P. [In fact in the absence of such P there are at most eight C's, so as soon as we reach n=9 we're already done.] –
> Noam D. Elkies
> Jun 8 at 2:44

Comment: Please include the reference of the answer by Noam D. Elkies by using the "share" option.

Comment: The original post was voted to be closed in mathoverflow so I deleted it; and then the comment by Prof Noam Elkies is invisible now.

Comment: Inversion in the circle of radius 1 around the origin    takes the circles to those tangent to the $x$ axis at   positive integers. The radii  have not yet been specified. Suppose the circle tangent at $1$  has radius $r$   while the circle tangent at $2$   has radius $s.$  These have a relationship caused by the two circles being tangent to each other. If they both have radius $1/2,$  then the radius over $3$  is also $1/2.$  **With radii $r,s$  unequal, what is the radius of the circle tangent to the $x$ axis at $3 \; ? \; \; $**

Comment: the algebra is a little worse if we use diameters, however the numbers are nicer. Invert around the origin, the result is circles tangent to the $x$ axis at integers. To be tangent to the neighbor circles, one possibility is all diameters $1.$  However, if circle at $1$ has diameter $D$  and $2$ has diameter $E,$   what is the relationship between $D$   and $E,$    and what is the diameter of the circle tangent to the $x$ axis at $3   \; ?  \; \; $  Then, diameter of the circle at $4?$

Answer (score 1):

This is what I had in mind. If you invert your original picture in the unit circle around the origin,  the $x$ axis is mapped to itself, all lines and circles are mapped to lines   or circles,  and all tangency is preserved. So you get circles tangent to the $x$ axis at positive integers.

The circles might all have diameter $1,$ that is the top row  in purple ink.

The circles might have varying diameters.   However, there is then an explicit relationship of diameters at consecutive integers, as that pair of circles must be tangent. **What is the relationship of diameters in my picture?**

The extreme is in the bottom row in red.

In these rows, there are evident horizontal lines that are tangent to all these circles, I did not draw those.   Those lines are mapped back to something nice when inverting my picture back to your original setting

[image]

Below is the middle row of circles, done over to include the new horizontal lines that are, together,  tangent to all the circles

[image]

Comment: Hi Will. This question evokes other interconnections such as those shown in this article https://digitalcommons.unl.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1001&context=mathmidexppap ...

Comment: @JeanMarie  HI. That's a nice exposition. They mention John Horton Conway and The Book of Numbers. The place I first saw Ford circles is probably Conway's book The Sensual Quadratic Form.

Answer (score 0):

The map $f(z)=\frac 1{\overline{z}}=\frac z{|z|^2}$ works. For example, it’s easy to check that the circle $|z-ri|=r$ of radius $r>0$ is mapped to the horizontal line $y=\frac 1{2r}.$

Now $f$ retains the conformal behavior (up to reflection) and maps circles (or lines) to circles (or lines). The points $\frac 1 n,n\in{\mathbb N}$ are mapped to $n,n\in{\mathbb N}.$ To check the claim, it suffices to examine those circles tangent at $x=n$. For simplicity, one looks at circles tangent at $x=1$ of radius $r_1$ and at $x=2$ of radius $r_2$ such that they are mutually tangent. By Pythagorean theorem, $r_1,r_2$ satisfy the relation $$1+(r_2-r_1)^2=(r_1+r_2)^2,$$ hence $$r_1r_2=\frac 14.$$ It follows that $r_2r_3=\frac 14,$ etc. Consequently $$r_1=r_3=r_5=\cdots, r_2=r_4=r_6=\cdots,$$ hence they are at most all tangent to two horizontal lines. Applying the inverse transformation then proves the claim. QED

**Remark**. In the particular case when $r_1=\frac 12,$ the circles will all be tangent to one horizontal line with equation $y= 1.$ Applying inverse transformation, this corresponds to the circle tangent at $x=1$ with equation $(x-1)^2+(y-1/2)^2=1/4$ and the circle tangent at $0$ with equation $\left|z-\frac 12i\right|=\frac 12$ that is tangent to the whole family of circles.